# Firebase table - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database with some information in it, that I just constructed a table:

```
    rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var name = snap.child("leagueName").val();
    var code = snap.key;
    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td> <button id="+code+" class='mdl-button mdl-js-button'>"+ name +" </button></td></tr>");});
```

So now I have arbitrary number of rows at my table, each has a button with it's unique ID. 
next step is that I want each of them to be a link to some other page.

Is there a way to retrieve these ID's to create a js click function with them? 
I mean I don't know what these ID's are and how many of them will be, since this is something the user will enter.

Maybe there's another more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for:

```
$('#table_body').on('click', 'btn', function() {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
  document.location = 'https:/your.new.url/leagues/' + $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Of course if you want the elements to just be a link to another page, you should really consider making them `<a href='...'>` elements, as those are the idiomatic way to model links to pages. And in that case, you could also simply inject the keys when you generate the row in the table:

```
$("#table_body").append("<tr><td> <a id="+code+" href='https:/your.new.url/leagues/"+code+"' class='mdl-button mdl-js-button'>"+ name +" </button></td></tr>");});
```